# How to get id of admin regions in Norway in OpenStreetMap?

Tags: openstreetmap, administrative-boundaries, norway

I need to get the id of the relations that are administrative (`boundary: administrative`) that have `admin_level` equal to `7` in Norway.

Is there any way to get them?

Comment: Did you tried the overpass-API already? http://overpass-turbo.eu

Comment: @Mapper : Thank you. That's a great tool! I certainly have to explore it better. Too bad I don't have the privilege to upvote your comment yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) query:

```
[out:json]
[timeout:90]
;
area(3601059668)->.searchArea;
relation
  ["boundary"="administrative"]
  ["admin_level"="7"]
  (area.searchArea);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

ID 3601059668 corresponds to the [relation ID 1059668](http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/1059668) (+3600000000) which is the administrative boundary of Norway.

You can [download the raw data from Overpass API](http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=%5Bout%3Ajson%5D%5Btimeout%3A90%5D%3Barea%283601059668%29%2D%3E%2EsearchArea%3Brelation%5B%22boundary%22%3D%22administrative%22%5D%5B%22admin%5Flevel%22%3D%227%22%5D%28area%2EsearchArea%29%3Bout%20body%3B%3E%3Bout%20skel%20qt%3B%0A) or [view the result on overpass turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/bKJ). Here, specifying a relation ID is not necessary since overpass turbo (although using the Overpass API as backend) supports some more advanced statements, like geocoding calls for or returning of corresponding relation IDs.

Comment: Could you just, kindly, explain the reason why we must add 3600000000 to the relation id?

Comment: It's a requirement from Overpass API and explained in the [language reference](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#By_element_id). OSM's data model consists of three basic elements (nodes, ways, relations) of which both ways and relations can be used to describe areas. Since each element has a separate ID space it's impossible to decide whether an ID refers to a way or a relation which Overpass API has to know in order to fetch the correct element. Therefore you have to add 2400000000 to node IDs and 3600000000 to area IDs. This could have been better solved I guess :\

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In deed it gives the feeling that better solutions could have been implemented.

Comment: the boundaries don't follow the coast but extend into the sea. it's the first case I found on osm. other countries have their boundaries follow the coast line